# actionbar overlaps Fragment content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I'm using navigation bar to switch over my fragments, but the fragment content is always being overlapped by the actionbar, how to avoid this?

I've tried to remove lines `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` but it did not change anything.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_violation_browser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_violation_browser"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_violation_browser_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here i placed 4 text rows

[image]

But when i run it on my device it looks like this...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have 3 views inside the `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`, only the first one is considered as content and the other two are considered as drawers.

Surround the `FrameLayout` with id `frame_container` and the `include` with layout `app_bar_violation_browser` by another FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following code to your fragment layout:

```
   android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
```

Especially, marginTop!

And, use that `<include` like this and do your stuffs on the referring layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/app_bar_violation_browser" />
```

And delete that `FrameLayout` and use it in your `Include`.

That should work then.